# Java text to ASCII converter with a loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to my first program text to ASCII converter, but I have some problems, it's explained inside the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AsciiConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Write some text here");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n"); // Scans whole text
        String myChars = scanner.next();
        int lenght = myChars.length(); // Checking length of text to use it as "while" ending value  
        int i = -1;
        int j = 0;
        do{
            String convert = myChars.substring(i++,j++); // taking first char, should be (0,1)...(1,2)... etc 
            int ascii = ('convert'/1); // I'm trying to do this, so it will show ascii code instead of letter, error: invalid character constant
            System.out.print(ascii); // Should convert all text to ascii symbols
        }
        while(j < lenght );
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: why u r using `'convert'` within `' '`? it is name of variable. just write `int ascii = (convert/1);`

Comment: Confused by the line `int ascii = ('convert'/1);`
What should that be doing?

Comment: Just a trick to get ASCII code as result :)

Comment: `charAt` will return the `char` value at a given position in a String.  `char` is a 16-bit unsigned number which is the numeric code for the character.  So, `System.out.println((int) myString.charAt(index));` will print the numeric value for the character at `index`.

Comment: `int ascii = ('convert'/1);` does not compile in java 8

Answer (score 2):

```
String x = "text"; // your scan text
for(int i =0; i< x.getLength(); x++){
    System.out.println((int)x.charAt(i)); // A = 65, B = 66...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Maybe use `Scanner.nextLine()`.)

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;
String ascii = Normalizer.normalize(myChars, Form.NFKD)
        .replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}", "");
```

This splits all accented chars like `ĉ` into `c` and a zero length `^`. And then all non-ascii (capital P = non-P) is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Write some text here");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n"); // Scans whole text
        String myChars = scanner.next();
        char[] charArray = myChars.toCharArray();
        for (char character : charArray) {
            System.out.println((int)character);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
```

This converts the string to a char array and then prints out the string representation of each character.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :) If an answer resloves your problem, generally you should click the arrow next to it to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
"int ascii = ('convert'/1);"
```

by

> int ascii= (int)convert;

This should work.

Comment: How do you cast a String to an int??

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AsciiConverter {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Write some text here");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n"); // Scans whole text
    String myChars = scanner.next();
    int lenght = myChars.length(); // Checking length of text to use it as "while" ending value  
    int i = -1;
    int j = 0;
    do{
        String convert = myChars.substring(i++,j++); // taking first char, should be (0,1)...(1,2)... etc 
        int ascii= (int)convert; // I'm trying to do this, so it will show ascii code instead of letter, error: invalid character constant
        System.out.print(ascii); // Should convert all text to ascii symbols
    }
    while(j < lenght );
    scanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Exactly how do you cast a String to an int??

Answer (score -1):

did you missed type casting the character to integer?
try this:

```
int ascii = (int) convert;
```

Comment: `convert` is a String.